# Where is my database stored in Slick? [Scala][Slick 3.0]

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'm not particularly sure if this is a valid question, but I was wondering where exactly my data base is stored in Slick

For example, if I follow the example at http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/gettingstarted.html

They create tables :

```
// Definition of the SUPPLIERS table
class Suppliers(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)](tag, "SUPPLIERS") {
  def id = column[Int]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey) // This is the primary key column
  def name = column[String]("SUP_NAME")
  def street = column[String]("STREET")
  def city = column[String]("CITY")
  def state = column[String]("STATE")
  def zip = column[String]("ZIP")
  // Every table needs a * projection with the same type as the table's type parameter
  def * = (id, name, street, city, state, zip)
}
val suppliers = TableQuery[Suppliers]

// Definition of the COFFEES table
class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)](tag, "COFFEES") {
  def name = column[String]("COF_NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
  def supID = column[Int]("SUP_ID")
  def price = column[Double]("PRICE")
  def sales = column[Int]("SALES")
  def total = column[Int]("TOTAL")
  def * = (name, supID, price, sales, total)
  // A reified foreign key relation that can be navigated to create a join
  def supplier = foreignKey("SUP_FK", supID, suppliers)(_.id)
}
val coffees = TableQuery[Coffees]
```

And then they fill it up with

```
 val setup = DBIO.seq(
  // Create the tables, including primary and foreign keys
  (suppliers.schema ++ coffees.schema).create,

  // Insert some suppliers
  suppliers += (101, "Acme, Inc.",      "99 Market Street", "Groundsville", "CA", "95199"),
  suppliers += ( 49, "Superior Coffee", "1 Party Place",    "Mendocino",    "CA", "95460"),
  suppliers += (150, "The High Ground", "100 Coffee Lane",  "Meadows",      "CA", "93966"),
  // Equivalent SQL code:
  // insert into SUPPLIERS(SUP_ID, SUP_NAME, STREET, CITY, STATE, ZIP) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)

  // Insert some coffees (using JDBC's batch insert feature, if supported by the DB)
  coffees ++= Seq(
    ("Colombian",         101, 7.99, 0, 0),
    ("French_Roast",       49, 8.99, 0, 0),
    ("Espresso",          150, 9.99, 0, 0),
    ("Colombian_Decaf",   101, 8.99, 0, 0),
    ("French_Roast_Decaf", 49, 9.99, 0, 0)
  )
  // Equivalent SQL code:
  // insert into COFFEES(COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, SALES, TOTAL) values (?,?,?,?,?)
)

val setupFuture = db.run(setup)
```

Does the database exist purely in memory?

If I fill in the database from a text file, does the database still only exist in memory?
If so, how would I transport it to disk?
Am I even on the right track here?

Comment: It says it [right here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/gettingstarted.html#database-configuration) that it uses H2 in 'in-memory mode'. You'd have to [remove `mem`](http://www.h2database.com/html/faq.html#connect) to have it write data to filesystem.

Comment: If I were to remove mem, where would it be saved, and in what format? How would I access it again? I'm assuming you mean remove  `url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test1"` here?

Comment: If you're asking where the files are stored, it's explained in H2 FAQ/manual, I linked right to it. You'd just access it by specifying the same connection string again (?). If you want to peek inside using other means - I doubt you'll have much luck, I'm pretty sure the file format is opaque.

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry, I've been through this entire document multiple times but I don't think I see what you see because I'm not really sure what I'm looking for. Do you mind specifying which parts of said document should I look at? I'm trying to figure out where the database files are stored if I were to rem mem

Comment: There you go: "When using database URLs like `jdbc:h2:~/test`, the database is stored in the user directory. For Windows, this is usually C:\Documents and Settings\<userName> or C:\Users\<userName>. If the base directory is not set (as in `jdbc:h2:test`), the database files are stored in the directory where the application is started (the current working directory) (...) The directory is created automatically if it does not yet exist. It is also possible to use the fully qualified directory name (and for Windows, drive name). Example: `jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/test`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slick doesn't "store" a database anywhere.  Slick is a library which allows you to access data in a database.  You generally specify which database you want to connect to using a jdbc "connection url" such as "jdbc:h2:mem:test1" in this case.  Jdbc is a standard Java API for accessing relational databases, and there are a lot of databases out there for which jdbc drivers exist.

So when using Slick, you're going to choose which database you want to use it with:  h2, postgres, mysql, oracle, sql server, etc.  You should consult the documentation of the database you have chosen to learn where it stores your data.

I believe the reason that Slick chose to use h2 for their getting started example is that h2 can run in "memory mode", in which the data is kept only in memory.  In this mode, the data is purely transient and is lost when your program terminates.  On the other hand, it's also really easy to run h2 in a persistent mode where data is stored on disk.  Further, you have the choice of running the database "embedded", or "client/server".

You really should consult the h2 documentation to understand more (http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).  In particular, the jdbc connection url gives you control over whether to connect to a transient, in-memory instance, an embedded instance, or a remote instance.  See http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url.

Comment: Hey thanks, this was what I was looking for. As a follow up, what's the difference between a transient and an in-memory instance?

Comment: I used those two adjectives as complementary to each other.  It's transient because it's in-memory and will be lost when the process terminates.